# Apply function on a list of tables by column

Tags: r

I have a list of table objects as such : `list(X1A.1145442 = structure(c(0.3204, 0.6796, 0.3645, 0.6355, 0.1615, 0.8385, 0.3266, 0.6734, 0.2884, 0.7116, 0.3042, 0.6958), .Dim = c(2L, 6L), class = "table", .Dimnames = list(x = c("1", "2"),c("ES1-5", "ES14-26", "ES27-38", "ES6-13", "SA1-13", "SA14-25"))), X1A.1158042 = structure(c(0.4437, 0.5563, 0.4264, 0.5736, 0.2308, 0.7692, 0.3896, 0.6104, 0.2997, 0.7003, 0.3148, 0.6852), .Dim = c(2L, 6L), class = "table", .Dimnames = list(x = c("1", "2"), c("ES1-5", "ES14-26", "ES27-38", "ES6-13", "SA1-13", "SA14-25"))))`

The list looks this way :

```
$`X1A.1145442`

x    ES1-5 ES14-26 ES27-38 ES6-13 SA1-13 SA14-25     
1 0.3204  0.3645  0.1615 0.3266 0.2884  0.3042
2 0.6796  0.6355  0.8385 0.6734 0.7116  0.6958

$X1A.1158042

x    ES1-5 ES14-26 ES27-38 ES6-13 SA1-13 SA14-25
1 0.4437  0.4264  0.2308 0.3896 0.2997  0.3148
2 0.5563  0.5736  0.7692 0.6104 0.7003  0.6852
```

I would like to obtain the minimum value for each element of the list of tables in a column wise fashion.

I tried something with lapply but without success. Could someone help me on that please.

Regards,

Alex

Comment: `lapply(x, addmargins, 1, min)` can be used to add a `min` row to each matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a `list` of `matric`es.  So the unit will be each element.  If we use `lapply`, then it will loop through each of the element unless it is a converted to a `data.frame`.  Here, we can make use of `apply` with `MARGIN` specified as 2 (for looping through columns)

```
lapply(lst1, function(x) apply(x, 2, min))
```

---

Or another option is `colMins` from `matrixStats`

```
library(matrixStats)
lapply(lst1, colMins)
```

Comment: could you explain me why `apply` works in the first solution nested within `lapply` ? I noticed the class of the objects of the list were coerced to `numeric`. so I guess it's not a `data.frame` and still  did work .

Comment: @AlexandreMondaini  Here, the `lst1` is a `list` of `matrices`.  With `apply`,functions can be applied in any matrix either columnwise (`MARGIN = 2`) or rowwise (`MARGIN = 1)`.  When we have a `list`, the usual functions that loop through the `list` are `lapply/sapply/vapply` etc.  Here, I choose `lapply` that loops through the list and then applies the function `min` columnwise on each of the matrices with `apply`.  Hope it is clear

Comment: `apply` can be used in both `matrix` or `data.frame`, while `lapply` works on `data.frame` columns as column is a unit in data.frame, while in `matrix`, the unit is  single element i.e. matrix is a vector with `dim` attributes